# Windows 11 does not recognize third monitor until plugging cable out and in

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-11, external-display

at home I connect my laptop with two external displays. Whenever my laptop goes to sleep mode, and I unlock it again, only one of the two external displays gets found. The other one will only show the desktop again after unplugging cable and putting it back in, and also turning monitor off and on again. The monitors are `HP E273q`. What can I do for detecting the third display automatically? Thanks in advance!

My PC:

```
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎15/‎2022
OS build    22621.819
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22636.1000.0

Device name My-Laptop
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.42 GHz
Installed RAM   16,0 GB (15,7 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
```

Graphic drivers:

```
Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
Driver Provider: Intel Corporation
Driver Date: 9/2/2022
Driver Version: 31.0.101.3616
```

Comment: Can you update both Video and Monitor drivers and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi John, I've added the driver information under I've found in the device manager under Display adapters. If any other information would be helpful, please let me know.

Comment: If the drivers are up to date (a) try a different monitor if you can, and (b) update BIOS to see if a BIOS issue is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

For me the way to solve this was getting a docking station and using two HDMI cables to connect the docking station with the mointors. Since my laptop doesn't have HDMI, I had previously used USB-C cables to connect the monitors with the laptop directly, which apparently caused the issue.